# How can we measure electronic excitation in some "nm"(nanometres)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy

I have no idea to which concept this belongs:

> The widest range over which electronic excitations in organic compounds occur, is
>
> A) 200 nm – 780 nm
>
> B) 220 nm– 500nm
>
> C) 250 nm– 700 nm
>
> D) 290 nm – 1000nm

Comment: Don't make junky tags, please.

Comment: @jonsca i didn't knew any related to it

Comment: So try to get as close as you can and if they are not pertinent, someone can put the right ones on.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking what wavelengths of light can cause electronic excitation in organic compounds, i.e. what energy photons correspond to the energy difference between the ground and excited states. They're not the same in all compounds (which is why different compounds have different absorbance spectra), but there is a range of energies in which most of the electronic transitions in organic compounds occur.

Comment: I think an important component of the question is whether, for example, there are compounds that will have electronic excitations  at 200 nm, 220, 250, 290nm, etc. and the same for the long wavelengths  (i.e., will anything have an electronic excitation at 1000 nm?)